# JavaScript Date Object's month index begins with 0

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, timestamp, google-visualization

My goal is to convert a timestamp from MySQL into a JavaScript Date object in an efficient manner.  Here is my current snippet that converts the MySQL timestamp into a formatted date in PHP:

```
<?php
// formats timestamp into following format: 2009, 7, 30
$date =  date("Y, n, j", strtotime($row["date"]));
?>
```

I am then using this `$date` value for a chart using Google's charting API which requires JavaScript Date object:

```
data.setValue(<?=$count;?>, 0, new Date(<?=$date;?>));
```

The problem is that the JavaScript Date object begins the month index with 0 so the output is always 1 month **in advance**.  What is the most efficient way in dealing with this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the title of this post implies that you're shocked that an index would equal zero. lol sensational

Comment: You're right.  This post was 3 years ago.  Now that I look back at it, it is kind of funny that I was surprised an index started from 0 =)

Comment: I think your surprise was justified in this case: a zero-indexed month value is completely unintuitive. Javascript's creators had the presence of mind not to zero-index the day value, or the year value for that matter (there was no year 0, so a zero-indexed year would be off by one). Why this logic didn't carry over into the month column is incomprehensible.

Comment: I have been searching for this for a whole month... Wait a minute... for zero months, I mean. Hrm. Javascript humor.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can feed the Date constructor a date in mm/dd/yyyy or yyyy/mm/dd format and it will convert it:

```
>>> new Date('7/30/2009');
Thu Jul 30 2009 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
>>> new Date('2009/7/30');
Thu Jul 30 2009 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

Comment: Thanks for this man. I've been raging for days wondering why my datepicker is calling July August. Turns out someone went full-loon and decided to get lazy with their pointer arithmetic implementing this.

For reference since its been asked around, the reason arrays in most languages start at zero is due to pointer arithmetic. When your trying to find the memory location of a fixed width series of strings, you basically take the base pointer, and add the index multiplied by cell/string length to get the pointer to the required value. 0 * index + base pointer = location for first item.

Comment: How do you make this work via the JSON response required for Google Charts Data source protocol? I've hit the same issue, but cannot format my response like this. JSON doesn't support a Date object, so Google have added a string extension hack e.g.:  `{"v":"Date(2009,7,30)"}` which makes June, but they do not support `{"v":"Date('2009/7/30')"}` or similar...

Answer (score 14):

You have to manually subtract that extra `1` from month number I'm afraid. JS Date object is a mess.

Comment: That is exactly what I was afraid of.  I was shocked to have found this out!

Comment: You were shocked to find out JS is a heaping mess of ugly stuff? :D

Comment: @AjayPatel - 'some cases', care to elaborate?

Comment: Remember boys and girls, the marketing people want us to write our servers on this confounded language! Ok, not constructive(have a laugh mods, its all in jest), but I just wanted to throw this out there. I'm still astonished at the inconsistency of zero indexing month but not year or day.

Comment: If you want to rain hate on the JS Date, you aren't stuck with it - one alternative I would highly recommend is [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), which wraps around the native Date and provides a variety of functionality (e.g. date comparisons, date arithmetic, parsing, formatted output).

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a date in the [Date String Representation compatible with the Google Charts DataTable](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#datestring) like

```
"Date(2015,0,31)" // note the quotes from the json string and the 0 for January
```

without walking through the query rows in php, you could have MySQL format it directly like this:

```
<?php
$sql = "
    SELECT 
        CONCAT('Date(', YEAR(datefield), ',', (MONTH(datefield)-1), ',', DAY(datefield), ')') AS gChartDate, 
        valuefield
    FROM 
        table 
    ORDER BY
        datefield
";
$query = $pdo->query($sql);
$fetchAll = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM); // fetch in not-associative array
array_unshift($fetchAll, [['type'=>'date', 'label'=>'date'], 'value']); // add title row
$json = json_encode($fetchAll, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

then in javascript:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo($json) ?>);
```