# Javascript day/month/year into form

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to get the month, day and year to be auto selected in a form. I'm sure this is pretty simple but I'm quite unfamiliar with Javascript. In the code below the month select is working fine but the day is always +1 of the actual day and the year is not working at all. If anyone can help it would be very appreciated! Thanks!

```
<form name="form" action="b.html" method="post">
    <select id="month" name="month">
        <option id="1" value="January">January</option>
        <option id="2" value="February">February</option>
        <option id="3" value="March">March</option>
        <option id="4" value="April">April</option>
        <option id="5" value="May">May</option>
        <option id="6" value="June">June</option>
        <option id="7" value="July">July</option>
        <option id="8" value="August">August</option>
        <option id="9" value="September">September</option>
        <option id="10" value="October">October</option>
        <option id="11" value="November">November</option>
        <option id="12" value="December">December</option>
    </select>
    /
    <select id="day" name="day">
        <option id="1" value="1">1</option>
        <option id="2" value="2">2</option>
        <option id="3" value="3">3</option>
        <option id="4" value="4">4</option>
        <option id="5" value="5">5</option>
        <option id="6" value="6">6</option>
        <option id="7" value="7">7</option>
        <option id="8" value="8">8</option>
        <option id="9" value="9">9</option>
        <option id="10" value="10">10</option>
        <option id="11" value="11">11</option>
        <option id="12" value="12">12</option>
        <option id="13" value="13">13</option>
        <option id="14" value="14">14</option>
        <option id="15" value="15">15</option>
        <option id="16" value="16">16</option>
        <option id="17" value="17">17</option>
        <option id="18" value="18">18</option>
        <option id="19" value="19">19</option>
        <option id="20" value="20">20</option>
        <option id="21" value="21">21</option>
        <option id="22" value="22">22</option>
        <option id="23" value="23">23</option>
        <option id="24" value="24">24</option>
        <option id="25" value="25">25</option>
        <option id="26" value="26">26</option>
        <option id="27" value="27">27</option>
        <option id="28" value="28">28</option>
        <option id="29" value="29">29</option>
        <option id="30" value="30">30</option>
        <option id="31" value="31">31</option>
    </select>
    /
    <select id="year" name="year">
        <option id="2012" value="2012">2012</option>
        <option id="2013" value="2013">2013</option>
        <option id="2014" value="2014">2014</option>
        <option id="2015" value="2015">2015</option>
        <option id="2016" value="2016">2016</option>
        <option id="2017" value="2013">2017</option>
        <option id="2018" value="2014">2018</option>
        <option id="2019" value="2015">2019</option>
        <option id="2020" value="2016">2020</option>
    </select>

    <script>
    var d = new Date();
    var month = d.getMonth();
    var day = d.getDate();
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    document.form.month[month].selected = month;
    document.form.day[day].selected = day;
    document.form.year[year].selected = year;
    </script>
</form>
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: "Not working" is _never_ a sufficient problem description.

Comment: I've never liked using `select` for date management. It's very easy to allow dates like Feb. 31st.

Comment: I think if you actually have a look at what values you are using you'll be able to figure it out pretty quick. Just remember that a `select` is an array, so the first element is at index value 0. Also for the year you have 9 options, look at what value you are using to select from the array.

Comment: @Matt, the answer you selected from rationalboss has a bug in it. You will find out when the calendar rolls around to January.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are trying to access the elements through their respective index. When you accessed month, it was a coincidence that it will display the correct month because `getMonth()` returns `0` for January. When you selected the third month (index=2), it correctly selected March as the element with `index=2`.

For the date and the year, I changed your code to `.value` instead. You cannot do this for month because the values you've used are January, February, March, etc, and not their indices.

```
<script>
    var d = new Date();
    var month = d.getMonth();
    var day = d.getDate();
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    document.form.month.options[month].selected = true;
    document.form.day.value = day;
    document.form.year.value = year;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks to you and everyone else that has answered the question!

Comment: This selected answer is buggy, It is setting a Boolean to a number. What happens in January? It FAILS!!!! -1

Answer (score 1):

You have ids that clash! ids are singular values on the page. Selected is a boolean and you are setting it to a number.

Get rid of the ids,

```
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth();
var day = d.getDate();
var year = d.getFullYear();
document.form.month.options[month].selected = true;
document.form.day.options[day-1].selected = true;
document.form.year.options[year-2012].selected = true;
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that the code above works on zero based index of the options. month is zero based so we do not need to subtract one. Need to subtract one from the day to make that zero based. Finally subtracting the first year possible makes it zero based for the year.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
var day = d.getDate();
...
document.form.year[year].selected = true;
```

should be

```
var day = d.getDate()-1;
...
document.form.year[year - 2012].selected = true;
```

The day must be subtract 1 because this part: `document.form.day[day]` is an array, remember array is started from 0 but the `getDate()` is started from 1.

Why you don't need to subtract 1 for the month part? Because [JavaScript Date Object's month index begins with 0!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208519/javascript-date-objects-month-index-begins-with-0)

Comment: Why are you setting a Boolean to a number?

Comment: I guess it would help to explain why you need to subtract 1. Your code makes it look like the date returned is incorrect, while you are trying to adjust the index offset.  In that way @epascarello's answer makes it much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

The options in the select-element are accessed by an index starting at [0].

Resulting in:

```
document.form.month[0].value is 'January'
document.form.day[0].value is 1;
document.form.year[0].selected is 2012;
```

Be sure to calculate your index correctly or use the value of your items as index:

```
var year = d.getFullYear();
document.getElementById('year').value = year;
```

And please remove the "id" attribute from your options. It's bad practice to have the same id twice in a document. It should be unique for elements.​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 0):

See my working solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/powtac/gVWrz/7/

```
document.form.month[month].selected = true;
document.form.day.value             = day;
document.form.year.value            = year;
```