# Get days of the week based on week number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

Is there a way to get the Sunday thru Saturday dates of the week based on week number?

For example the current week number is 32, so I would want an array (or some return type) as such:

```
["Sunday, July 3rd, 2016", "Monday, July 4th, 2016".... etc  ]
```

The documentation [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/week/) states that use can use the syntax below, however this seems to simply gives me the current day (unless I'm reading the output wrong).

```
moment().weeks(32)
```

Output: `Fri Aug 05 2016 11:19:39 GMT-0400`

Comment: Did you install `moment js`? You can install it from npm, it's all explained at the top of the page you linked.

Comment: [this looks most of the way to what you need](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590500/javascript-calculate-date-from-week-number)

Comment: The doc says: "When setting the week of the year, the day of the week is retained."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would suggest to not go for additional libraries. Once you get first day for given week number using moment().weeks(32), write a simple method to return next seven days using moment().add() method.