# How to get "start date" and "end date" of a week from MYSQL when week number is available?

Tags: php, mysql, week-number

The week() function of MySql gives number of week from 0-53.

I have a weeknumber and I want to have the "*start date*" and "*end date*" of the week represented by weeknumber. **How can I do that?**

If there is no way of getting "start date" and "end date" of a week directly, how can I the "start week day" and "end week day" from the week number? I tried to get the first day (Monday) of the week by using the following query:-

```
$currentWeek = 7;
for($w = 0; $w <= $currentWeek; $w++)
{
    $actualWeek = intval($w + 1);
    if($w < 10)
        $queryWeek = '0'.$actualWeek;
    else
        $queryWeek = $actualWeek;
    $thisYearWeek = date('Y').$queryWeek;
    $weekMondayQuery = $this->CustomerPayment->query("SELECT STR_TO_DATE('$thisYearWeek', '%X%V %W')");
}
```

The Jan 1, 2018 was Monday. For the First week, ie. when `$thisYearWeek = '201801'`, I am getting Monday date as **2018-01-08** instead of **2018-01-01**.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590500/javascript-calculate-date-from-week-number

Answer (score 2):

How about adding days to the first Monday in a year?

Assuming `2018-01-01` is a Monday in a first week and the number of week you need is `$num_week`:

```
SELECT '2018-01-01' + INTERVAL ($num_week-1)*7 DAY as start, 
       '2018-01-01' + INTERVAL $num_week*7-1 DAY as end;
```

Which for the 7th week gives:

```
>>> SELECT '2018-01-01' + INTERVAL 42 DAY as start, 
           '2018-01-01' + INTERVAL 48 DAY as end;

start       end
2018-02-12  2018-02-18
```

EDIT: Added correction if the first day of the year is not a Monday. But your implementation will depend on how you count weeks with a `week()` function:

```
>>> select '2016-01-01'+interval ($num_week-week('2016-01-01', 1))*7 - weekday('2016-01-01') day as start, 
           '2016-01-01'+interval ($num_week-week('2016-01-01', 1)+1)*7-1 - weekday('2016-01-01') day as end;

start       end
2016-02-15  2016-02-21

>>> select '2017-01-01'+interval ($num_week-week('2017-01-01', 1))*7 - weekday('2017-01-01') day as start, 
           '2017-01-01'+interval ($num_week-week('2017-01-01', 1)+1)*7-1 - weekday('2017-01-01') day as end;

start       end
2017-02-13  2017-02-19
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the week number, we can do the following (most variables should be intuitive, but `sow` is Start Of Week):

```
SET @weeknum=42;
SET @week=DATE_ADD('2018-01-01', INTERVAL @weeknum WEEK);
SET @dow=DAYOFWEEK(@week)-1;
SET @sow=DATE_SUB(@week, INTERVAL @dow DAY);
SELECT @week, @dow, @sow;
SELECT @sow AS startDay, DATE_ADD(@sow, INTERVAL +6 DAY) AS endDay;
```

This tells us that week 42 for 2018 starts on 2018-10-21 and ends on 2018-10-27 ... remember that weeks of the year are zero-indexed using this technique. Days of the week as returned by MySQL are 1-indexed, hence the subtraction in `@dow` assignment.

---

The PHP equivalent of this is somewhat easier:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('sunday last week '.date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2018-01-01 +42 weeks'))))
```

which returns: `2018-10-21` ... using "last week" because it considers monday the first day of the week.