# mysql convert week number to date range of week

Tags: mysql

Is there any way week can get date range based on week number and year inputs? check this image

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48724512/how-to-get-start-date-and-end-date-of-a-week-from-mysql-when-week-number-is

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert number of week into date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078730/how-to-convert-number-of-week-into-date)

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL documentation gives you a hint for [a possible solution](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

> You cannot use format `%X%V` to convert a year-week string to a date because the combination of a year and week does not uniquely identify a year and month if the week crosses a month boundary. To convert a year-week to a date, you should also specify the weekday:
>
> ```
> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('200442 Monday', '%X%V %W');
>   -> '2004-10-18'
> ```

So you can use the following solution, using [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and [`DATE_ADD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) to get the start and end date value of a specific the week:

```
SELECT 
    STR_TO_DATE('2019-04 Monday', '%X-%V %W') AS `start`, 
    DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('2019-04 Monday', '%X-%V %W'), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AS `end`
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b9063db013841df1e58226d09a60cedf)