# Javascript - How do i get every date in a week from a given week number and year

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, week-number

How do I get every weekday (monday through friday) in a week from a given week number

input

```
var weekNumber = "week + " " + year"; //"35 2020"
```

Wanted output

```
var weekArray = ["2020-08-24", "2020-08-25", "2020-08-26", "2020-08-27", "2020-08-28"];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript calculate date from week number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590500/javascript-calculate-date-from-week-number)

Comment: @Justinas not completely it returns the first and last date in a week. + i am stupid and dont know what to do if  the week starts in one month and ends in another

Comment: You have start date, then you use momentJs to loop 7 times and in each iteration add date to `weekArray`

Comment: The purpose of this site is not to write code for you, it's to help you with code you've written. The [answer linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590500/javascript-calculate-date-from-week-number) by @Justinas is all you need to get started, after that it's just a matter of looping over the days of the week and formatting the output. Those topics are also covered here in multiple previous questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example building on top of:  [javascript calculate date from week number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590500/javascript-calculate-date-from-week-number)

Get the first date of the week, then return an array of 7 elements, incrementing the date for each element.

If the day number goes above the number of days in the month, then add one to the month `temp.m` and reset the day `temp.d` equal to one.

```js
function getISOWeek(w, y) {
    var simple = new Date(y, 0, 1 + (w - 1) * 7);
    var dow = simple.getDay();
    var ISOweekStart = simple;
    if (dow <= 4)
        ISOweekStart.setDate(simple.getDate() - simple.getDay() + 1);
    else
        ISOweekStart.setDate(simple.getDate() + 8 - simple.getDay());
    const temp = {
      d: ISOweekStart.getDate(),
      m: ISOweekStart.getMonth(),
      y: ISOweekStart.getFullYear(),
    }
    //console.log(ISOweekStart)
    const numDaysInMonth = new Date(temp.y, temp.m + 1, 0).getDate()
    
    return Array.from({length: 7}, _ => {
      if (temp.d > numDaysInMonth){
        temp.m +=1;
        temp.d = 1;
        // not needed, Date(2020, 12, 1) == Date(2021, 0, 1)
        /*if (temp.m >= 12){
          temp.m = 0
          temp.y +=1
        }*/
      }      
      return new Date(temp.y, temp.m, temp.d++).toUTCString()
    });
}

// var weekNumber = "week + " " + year"; //"35 2020"
const weekNumber = "53 2020";

const weekYearArr = weekNumber.split(" ").map(n => parseInt(n))

const weekOut = getISOWeek(...weekYearArr) 

console.log(weekOut);
```

Input: "35 2020"

Output:

```js
[
  "Sun, 23 Aug 2020 22:00:00 GMT",
  "Mon, 24 Aug 2020 22:00:00 GMT",
  "Tue, 25 Aug 2020 22:00:00 GMT",
  "Wed, 26 Aug 2020 22:00:00 GMT",
  "Thu, 27 Aug 2020 22:00:00 GMT",
  "Fri, 28 Aug 2020 22:00:00 GMT",
  "Sat, 29 Aug 2020 22:00:00 GMT"
]
```

input : "36 2020"

output:

```js
[
  "Sun, 30 Aug 2020 22:00:00 GMT",
  "Mon, 31 Aug 2020 22:00:00 GMT",
  "Tue, 01 Sep 2020 22:00:00 GMT",
  "Wed, 02 Sep 2020 22:00:00 GMT",
  "Thu, 03 Sep 2020 22:00:00 GMT",
  "Fri, 04 Sep 2020 22:00:00 GMT",
  "Sat, 05 Sep 2020 22:00:00 GMT"
]
```