# How to get from 2022-W03 date range

Tags: javascript

i have one issue.
How to get from this: 2022-W01 date range ?
like this: 2022-01-03 - 2022-01-09

```js
function geeks() {
var link = document.getElementById("gfg").value;
document.getElementById("GFG").innerHTML = link;
}
```

```html
<label for="uname" style="color:green">
    <b>Select week</b>
</label>
             
<input type="week" id="gfg" placeholder="Enter week">
             
<br><br>
                 
<button type="button" onclick="geeks()">Click</button>
             
<p id="GFG"></p>
```

if is possible need get one value to variable $start and next variable $end into php.
Thanks.

Comment: remove every tag but javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate date from week number in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590500/calculate-date-from-week-number-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks i resolve problem Another way...

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    moment.locale('en', {
      week: { dow: 1 } // Monday is the first day of the week
    });

  //Initialize the datePicker(I have taken format as mm-dd-yyyy, you can     //have your owh)
  $("#weeklyDatePicker").datetimepicker({
      format: 'MM-DD-YYYY'
  });

   //Get the value of Start and End of Week
  $('#weeklyDatePicker').on('dp.change', function (e) {
      var value = $("#weeklyDatePicker").val();
      var firstDate = moment(value, "MM-DD-YYYY").day(1).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
      var lastDate =  moment(value, "MM-DD-YYYY").day(7).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
      $("#weeklyDatePicker").val(firstDate);
      $("#weeklyDatePicker2").val(lastDate);
  });
});
```

```css
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget tr:hover {
    background-color: #808080;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
            <div class="input-group" id="DateDemo">
            <form method="post">
              <input type='text' id='weeklyDatePicker' placeholder="Start" />
              <input type='text' id='weeklyDatePicker2' placeholder="end" />
              </form>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```