# DateTime new Date(params) in javascript is faster by 1 month

Tags: javascript, datetime, sails.js

It is very weird but it seems that new Date(params), when passed in the correct format of year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds, it is ahead by 1 month.

Take a look at the following implementation:

```
  // The format below needs to be changed according to req.param('dateTime')
  // dateTime format is as follows: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
  var dateTime = report['dateTime'];
  console.log('dateTime: '+dateTime);
  var dateTimeSplit = dateTime.split(' ');
  var dateSplit = dateTimeSplit[0].split('/');
  var timeSplit = dateTimeSplit[1].split(':');
  var day = parseInt(dateSplit[0]);
  var month = parseInt(dateSplit[1]);
  var year = parseInt(dateSplit[2]);
  var hour = parseInt(timeSplit[0]);
  var minute = parseInt(timeSplit[1]);
  var second = parseInt(timeSplit[2]);
  var createdAt = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, 0);
  console.log('createdAt: '+createdAt);
```

And the results from the logs are:

```
Feb 09 04:13:46 sails-wusrs app/web.1:  createdAt: Mon Mar 09 2015 12:02:24 GMT+0000 (UTC) 
Feb 09 04:13:46 sails-wusrs app/web.1:  dateTime: 09/02/2015 12:02:24
```

This server is running on heroku and it's weird that the log of createdAt is in front of dateTime. Everything else is alright, except for the month. 02 is Feb right? I'm so confused. Thanks for any help!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Date Object's month index begins with 0!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208519/javascript-date-objects-month-index-begins-with-0)

Comment: @qantas go easy here. I wouldnt have asked if I knew it started from 0. Yea I should have read the docs though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Month in javascript datetime starts from 0.

http://javascript.info/tutorial/datetime-functions

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Geez. My bad for not spotting that in the docs.